# Empty space under iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextview

In my iOS app, after presenting the keyboard a second time, there is a blank space under the keyboard.

[image: Keyboard space]

The space hides after pressing `.?123`.

I removed `keyboardWillShowNotification` and `keyboardWillHideNotification` and the same thing happens. I resize the `UITextView` at `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`, but I removed code to resize and the same thing happens.

It doesn't happen with my iPhone 7 but it happens with my iPad 6th gen. That's very strange because it's just on my app in this specific Text View.

Does that happened to someone? I can't find anything in Google.

Here is the source code of the View Controller: https://github.com/ColdGrub1384/Pyto/blob/master/Pyto/View%20Controllers/EditorViewController.swift

I use a view containing an `UITextView` inside it for syntax highlighting, but that has nothing to do with the bug because I also tested with a standard `UITextView`.

Comment: Can you please add the code out here?

Comment: looks like apple's bug..

Comment: @KarthickRamesh I updated the question

Comment: Make a dummy app with just the `UITextView` on the screen, and check if this issue is reproducible with it. If it's not, the problem can be caused by custom text view implementation.

Comment: @DisableR Same thing with a standard `UITextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS / iPadOS 13 fixes this bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc protocol KeyboardConstraintListener: class
{
func didOpenKeyboard()
func didCloseKeyboard()
}

class KeyboardConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint
{
@IBOutlet
weak var listener: KeyboardConstraintListener?

@IBInspectable
var skipAutoCalculateMarginToBottom: Bool = false

@IBInspectable
var keepMarginWhenOpen: Bool = false

private var originalConstant: CGFloat = 0.0

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.originalConstant = self.constant

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow),
                                           name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
                                           object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide),
                                           name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
                                           object: nil)
}

deinit
{
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification)
{
    self.listener?.didOpenKeyboard()
    self.updateConstant(notification: notification, showing: true)
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification)
{
    self.listener?.didCloseKeyboard()
    self.updateConstant(notification: notification, showing: false)
}

private func updateConstant(notification: Notification, showing: Bool)
{
    let duration: TimeInterval = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double) ?? 0.2

    guard let endFrame = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else
    {
        return
    }

    guard let firstView: UIView = self.getView(item: self.firstItem) else
    {
        return
    }

    guard let secondView: UIView = self.getView(item: self.secondItem) else
    {
        return
    }

    guard let superview: UIView = firstView.superview else
    {
        return
    }

    let keyboardHeight: CGFloat = (showing ? max(endFrame.size.height - self.modifier(view: secondView), 0.0) : 0.0)

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    superview.layoutIfNeeded()
    CATransaction.commit()

    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: duration,
        delay: 0,
        options: [.curveLinear],
        animations:
        {
            self.constant = keyboardHeight + self.originalConstant
            superview.layoutIfNeeded()
    },
        completion: nil)
}

private func modifier(view: UIView) -> CGFloat
{
    guard let window: UIWindow = view.window else
    {
        return 0.0
    }

    guard let superview: UIView = view.superview else
    {
        return 0.0
    }

    guard !self.skipAutoCalculateMarginToBottom else
    {
        return 0.0
    }

    let origin: CGPoint = superview.convert(view.frame.origin, to: nil)
    let bottom = origin.y + view.bounds.size.height
    let expand = window.bounds.size.height - bottom
    return expand - (self.constant - self.originalConstant) - (self.keepMarginWhenOpen ? self.originalConstant : 0.0)
}

private func getView(item: AnyObject?) -> UIView?
{
    if let view = item as? UIView
    {
        return view
    }
    else if let view = (item as? UILayoutGuide)?.owningView
    {
        return view
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

Create a constraint such that textView.bottom = safeArea.bottom

Comment: Thank you for answering but, I don't think that should fix the issue because it happens even if the view is not resized. How should I initialize this constraint in code without storyboard?

Comment: extension UIView {
  var safeBottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
      return self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
    }
    return self.bottomAnchor
  }
}
In the code you can set it as self.textView.bottomAnchor = self.view.safeBottomAnchor